# Append zeros to ssis derived column

Tags: sql, expression, ssas, derived, zipcode

Hi I am  loading data from flat file to my table through SSAS I want to derive a conditional column  to append zeros to is numeric data in the  zip code column when the length is <5
Derived Column Expression I am using  :  (CustomerZipCode!="[A-Za-z]")&&(LEN(CustomerZipCode) < 5) ? RIGHT(("00000" + CustomerZipCode),5) : CustomerZipCode

[ForExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk9me.png) 
the above expression is not working,request to guide me

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for SSIS?  My last answer assumed that this was an SSAS column because the SSAS tag.  If this is a date load via SSIS, you can use a Script Component to do this instead of a Derived Column.  The example below uses C# and the CustomerZipCode column will need to be added in the Input Columns pane with the `ReadWrite` usage type.  The `TryParse` method checks if the column is numeric and will return false if the column contains any text.  The String constructor is used to create the `zeroesToAppend` string, which is set to the number of zeroes below 5 that the length of the column is, and afterwards this is added to the beginning of the column.  This will go in the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method, which is executed once for each row from the input.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(Row.CustomerZipCode, out i) && Row.CustomerZipCode.Length < 5)
    {
        string zeroesToAppend = new String('0', 5 - Row.CustomerZipCode.Length);

        Row.name = String.Concat(zeroesToAppend, Row.CustomerZipCode);
    }
}
```